# Limit number of characters to show in a string, but show all characters of same string in modal without php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel of news.

```
<div class="news-1">
<h4>Title</h4>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
<a href="#">Show Post</a>
<div class="news-2">
<h4>Title</h4>
<p>Content</p>
<a href="#">Show Post</a>
</div>
```

And Im using https://github.com/joemottershaw/litebox to pop-up these new. Once I press Show Post, it copies all info between `<div class="news-#">` and `</div>` and places it into a overlay modal. So If I apply function to limit characters in `<p>Content</p>`, it will be limited in pop-up modal too. Is there any jquery trick/hack to limit number of characters in a string if it is located in certain container? So I could, for example, wrap `<div class="news-#">` and `</div>` with id="not-modal" containing container, and target content in `<p>Content</p>`, but once modal pop-ups, as it takes only content starting from class="news-#", it wouldnt crop the string? Or any alternative?
For beter clarity:
If `<p class/id?>Long string</p>` is wrapped in container with id/class="not-modal", truncate string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var substringLength = 50;
$("div[class|='news']").each(function(index, element){
    var p = $(element).find("p");   
    var truncated = p.text().substring(0, substringLength);
    p.addClass("modal");
    p.after("<p class=\"not-modal\">"+truncated+"</p>");
});
```

then in your css style take care of showing one and hiding the other and viceversa.

Comment: At first I couldnt understand, why It's not working. Apparently, twitter bootstrap has class modal, so It was already taken. Picked another namespace. Great solution, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wrap method of jQuery

```
 $("your long string").wrap("<div class='not-modal'></div>");
```

For more info : http://api.jquery.com/wrap/